# upload( ) of object FileTransfert not working on some android devices

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, typescript, ionic3

I developed a mobile app to help sharing things. The user has to give infos about what he is sending and he can add a picture of the object. So i used the cordova file, camera and fileTransfert plugins. It worked fine on most of the devices i tested on, but i discovered that in some other phone, it doesn't. While doing some tests and research on one of those phones, i discovered that the upload() method of FileTransfert i use to send images to online server seems like not able to reach the folder where the image is stored. Here is a sample of my code. Would you please help me to confirm if i am rigth and how to make those phones to be able to post pictures on the platform?

```
public presentActionSheet(picture) {
 if(this.translateService.currentLang=='fr'){

  let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
  title: 'Quelle est la source?',
  buttons: [
    {
      icon: 'images',
      text: 'Mon téléphone',
      handler: () => {
        this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, picture);
      }
    },
    {
      icon: 'camera',
      text: 'Ma Camera',
      handler: () => {
        this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, picture);
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Annuler',
      role: 'cancel'
    }
  ]
});
actionSheet.present();

}else{

  let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
  title: 'What is the source?',
  buttons: [
    {
      icon: 'images',
      text: 'My Phone',
      handler: () => {
        this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, picture);
      }
    },
    {
      icon: 'camera',
      text: 'My Camera',
      handler: () => {
        this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, picture);
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel'
    }
  ]
});
actionSheet.present();

}
  };

  presentToast(message_error) {
  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: message_error,
    cssClass: 'alert-box',
    position: 'middle',
    showCloseButton: true,
    closeButtonText: "OK"
  });
   toast.present();
}

//Here is the function to take a picture

public takePicture(sourceType, picture) {
  // Create options for the Camera Dialog
  var options = {
    quality: 100,
    sourceType: sourceType,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation: true
  };



// Get the data of an image
  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
    // Special handling for Android library
    if (this.platform.is('android') && sourceType === this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
      this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath)
        .then(filePath => {
          let correctPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imagePath.lastIndexOf('?'));
          this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName(), picture);
        });
    } else {
      console.log('In the else condition');
      var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      var correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName(), picture);
    }
  }, (err) => {
    if(this.translateService.currentLang=='fr'){
      this.presentToast('Erreur, pas d\'image selectionnée.');
    }else{
      this.presentToast('Error, no image selected.');
    }
  });
}

  // Create a new name for the image
  private createFileName() {
    var d = new Date(),
    n = d.getTime(),
    newFileName =  n + ".jpg";
    return newFileName;
  }

  // Copy the image to a local folder
  //cordova.file.dataDirectory
  private copyFileToLocalDir(namePath, currentName, newFileName, picture) {
    this.file.copyFile(namePath, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(success => {
      if(picture == "imageOne"){
        this.mainImage = newFileName;
      }else if(picture == "imageTwo"){
        this.secondImage = newFileName;
      }else{
        this.thirdImage = newFileName;
      }
      //this.lastImage = newFileName;
    }, error => {
      if(this.translateService.currentLang=='fr'){
        this.presentToast('Erreur, le fichier n\'a pas pu etre sauvegardé.');
      }else{
        this.presentToast('Error, file could not be saved.');
      }
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  // Always get the accurate path to your apps folder
  public pathForImage(img) {
    if (img === null) {
      return '';
    } else {
      return cordova.file.dataDirectory + img;
    }
  }

  public uploadImage(picture) {
  // Destination URL
  var url = "http://donation.oneclub1.org/donation-new/web/api/upload/image?context=donations";

  // File for Upload
  var targetPath: any;
  if(picture == "imageOne"){
       targetPath = this.pathForImage(this.mainImage);
      }else if(picture == "imageTwo"){
        targetPath = this.pathForImage(this.secondImage);
      }else{
        targetPath = this.pathForImage(this.thirdImage);
      }

  // File name only

  var filename: any;
  if(picture == "imageOne"){
       filename = this.mainImage;
      }else if(picture == "imageTwo"){
        filename = this.secondImage;
      }else{
        filename = this.thirdImage;
      }

  var options = {
    fileKey: "file",
    fileName: filename,
    chunkedMode: false,
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    params : {'fileName': filename}
  };

  const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();


  // Use the FileTransfer to upload the image
  return fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options);/*.then(data => {
    if(picture == "imageOne"){
       this.mainImageLocal = parseInt(data.response);
      }else if(picture == "imageTwo"){
        this.secondImageLocal = parseInt(data.response);
      }else{
        this.thirdImageLocal = parseInt(data.response);
      }
      //this.presentToast('this is your image id'+this.mainImageLocal);

  }, err => {
    this.loading.dismissAll();
    this.presentToast('Error while uploading file.');
  })*/;

}


  publish(){


  if(this.mainImage!=null){



    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: this.content2,
    });
    this.loading.present();

     //var categoryId: number;
    for(let parent of this.categories){
      if(parent.name == this.asking_form_group.value.subcategory){
        this.categoryId=parent.id;
        console.log('Id found and it is:'+this.categoryId);
        break;
      };
    };

    //var userId: number;
    if(localStorage.getItem('userId')){
      this.userId= parseInt(localStorage.getItem('userId'));
      console.log('got the user id in nmber:'+this.userId);
    };

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });



    this.uploadImage('imageOne').then(data => {

      this.mainImageLocal = parseInt(data.response);

              this.postParams = {
               name: this.asking_form_group.value.name,
               category: this.categoryId,
               description: this.asking_form_group.value.description,
               image: this.mainImageLocal,
               user: this.userId
           }

             this.http.post(this.Api+"/donations/requests?api_key="+localStorage.getItem('userApiKey'), this.postParams, options).map(res => res.json())
              .subscribe(data => {
                 this.loading.dismissAll();
                 if(this.translateService.currentLang=='fr'){
                 this.presentToast('Félicitations!!Votre demande a été postée sur la plateforme!')
                }else{
                  this.presentToast ('Congratulations !! Your request has been posted on the platform!')
                }

                 this.events.publish('ask:posted', 1);
                 this.navCtrl.setRoot(Dashboard);
               }, error => {
                console.log(error);
                //this.asking_form_group.reset();
                this.testor = error.response;
                this.loading.dismissAll();
                this.presentToast(this.error);
              });


    });



  }else{
            this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: this.content2,
            });
            this.loading.present();

            //var categoryId: number;
            for(let parent of this.categories){
              if(parent.name == this.asking_form_group.value.subcategory){
                this.categoryId=parent.id;
                console.log('Id found and it is:'+this.categoryId);
                break;
              };
            };

            if(localStorage.getItem('userId')){
              this.userId= parseInt(localStorage.getItem('userId'));
              console.log('got the user id in nmber:'+this.userId);
            };

            var headers = new Headers();
            headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });



            this.postParams = {
               name: this.asking_form_group.value.name,
               category: this.categoryId,
               description: this.asking_form_group.value.description,
               image: this.mainImageLocal,
               user: this.userId
           }


             this.http.post(this.Api+"/donations/requests?api_key="+localStorage.getItem('userApiKey'), this.postParams, options).map(res => res.json())
              .subscribe(data => {
                 this.loading.dismissAll();
                 if(this.translateService.currentLang=='fr'){
                 this.presentToast('Félicitations!!Votre demande a été postée sur la plateforme!')
                }else{
                  this.presentToast ('Congratulations !! Your request has been posted on the platform!')
                }
                 this.events.publish('ask:posted', 1);
                 this.navCtrl.setRoot(Dashboard);
               }, error => {
                console.log(error);
                //this.asking_form_group.reset();
                this.testor = error.response;
                this.loading.dismissAll();
                this.presentToast(this.error);
              });

        };

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i found what the issue was and i fogot to put it here. The problem was actually about filesize. Filetransfert default limit is 7.5Mo. Sending file greater than that would fail. In some phones, camera default configurations put the picture size to 8 or greater Mpx. So that why it could not work in those phones.